# Video creation with ffmpeg: video gets created but not playable

Tags: video, ffmpeg, colors, libraries, pictures

I just started using ffmpeg to create a video out of .png files. I read that the RGB can be conflict for the video encoder but I cannot solve the problem with the code I found in this forum. The file gets created but it does not use the added lib encoder to change color sceme. 
My code:

```
.\ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i 0000.png -i 0001.png -i 0002.png -i 0003.png -i 0004.png -i 0005.png -i 0006.png -i 0007.png -i 0008.png -i 0009.png -i 0010.png -i 0011.png -i 0012.png -i 0013.png -i 0014.png -i 0015.png -i 0016.png -i 0017.png -i 0018.png -i 0019.png -i 0020.png -i 0021.png -i 0022.png -i 0023.png -i 0024.png -i 0025.png -i 0026.png -i 0027.png -i 0028.png -i 0029.png -i 0030.png -i 0031.png -i 0032.png -i 0033.png -i 0034.png -i 0035.png -i 0036.png -i 0037.png -i 0038.png -i 0039.png -i 0040.png -i 0041.png -i 0042.png -i 0043.png -i 0044.png -i 0045.png -i 0046.png -i 0047.png -i 0048.png -i 0049.png -i 0050.png -i 0051.png -i 0052.png -i 0053.png -i 0054.png -i 0055.png -i 0056.png -i 0057.png -i 0058.png -i 0059.png -i 0060.png -i 0061.png -i 0062.png -i 0063.png -i 0064.png -i 0065.png -i 0066.png -i 0067.png -i 0068.png -i 0069.png -i 0070.png -i 0071.png -i 0072.png -i 0073.png -i 0074.png -i 0075.png -i 0076.png -i 0077.png -i 0078.png -i 0079.png -i 0080.png -i 0081.png -i 0082.png -i 0083.png -i 0084.png -i 0085.png -i 0086.png -i 0087.png -i 0088.png -i 0089.png -i 0090.png -i 0091.png -i 0092.png -i 0093.png -i 0094.png -i 0095.png -i 0096.png -i 0097.png -i 0098.png -i 0099.png -i 0100.png -i 0101.png -i 0102.png -i 0103.png -i 0104.png -i 0105.png -i 0106.png -i 0107.png -i 0108.png -i 0109.png -i 0110.png -i 0111.png -i 0112.png -i 0113.png -i 0114.png -i 0115.png -i 0116.png -i 0117.png -i 0118.png -i 0119.png -i 0120.png output.mp4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p
```

Full command output:

```
PS C:\tmp> .\ffmpeg -r 1/5 
-i 0000.png -i 0001.png -i 0002.png -i 003.png -i 0004.png -i 0005.png -i 0006.png -i 0007.png -i 0008.png -i 0009.png -i 0010.png -i 0011.png -i 0012.png -i 0013.png -i 0014.png -i 0015.png -i 016.png -i 0017.png -i 0018.png -i 0019.png -i 0020.png -i 0021.png -i 0022.png -i 0023.png -i 0024.png -i 0025.png -i 0026.png -i 0027.png -i 0028.png -i 0029.png -i 0030.png -i 0031.png -i 0032.png -i 0033.png -i 0034.png -i 0035.png -i 0036.png -i 0037.png -i 0038.png -i 0039.png -i 0040.png -i 0041.png -i 0042.png -i 0043.png -i 0044.png -i 0045.png -i 0046.png -i 0047.png -i 0048.png -i 0049.png -i 0050.png -i 0051.png -i 0052.png -i 0053.png -i 0054.png -i 0055.png -i 0056.png -i 0057.png -i 0058.png -i 0059.png -i 0060.png -i 0061.png -i 0062.png -i 0063.png -i 0064.png -i 0065.png -i 0066.png -i 0067.png -i 0068.png -i 0069.png -i 0070.png -i 0071.png -i 0072.png -i 0073.png -i 0074.png -i 0075.png -i 0076.png -i 0077.png -i 0078.png -i 0079.png -i 0080.png -i 0081.png -i 0082.png -i 0083.png -i 0084.png -i 0085.png -i 0086.png -i 0087.png -i 0088.png -i 0089.png -i 0090.png -i 0091.png -i 0092.png -i 0093.png -i 0094.png -i 0095.png -i 0096.png -i 0097.png -i 0098.png -i 0099.png -i 0100.png -i 0101.png -i 0102.png -i 0103.png -i 0104.png -i 0105.png -i 0106.png -i 0107.png -i 0108.png -i 0109.png -i 0110.png -i 0111.png -i 0112.png -i 0113.png -i 0114.png -i 0115.png -i 0116.png -i 0117.png -i 0118.png -i 0119.png -i 0120.png 
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-87871-g7480f232d2 
Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx  
libavutil      55. 79.100 / 55. 79.100  
libavcodec     57.108.100 / 57.108.100  
libavformat    57. 84.100 / 57. 84.100  
libavdevice    57. 11.100 / 57. 11.100  
libavfilter     6.108.100 /  6.108.100  
libswscale      4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100  
libswresample   2. 10.100 /  2. 10.100  
libpostproc    54.  8.100 / 54.  8.100 
Input #0, png_pipe, from '0000.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A    
Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #1, png_pipe, from '0001.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A    
Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #2, png_pipe, from '0002.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #3, png_pipe, from '0003.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A    
Stream #3:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #4, png_pipe, from '0004.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A    
Stream #4:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #5, png_pipe, from '0005.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A    
Stream #5:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #6, png_pipe, from '0006.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #6:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #7, png_pipe, from '0007.png': Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #7:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #8, png_pipe, from '0008.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #8:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #9, png_pipe, from '0009.png': Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #9:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #10, png_pipe, from '0010.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #10:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #11, png_pipe, from '0011.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #11:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #12, png_pipe, from '0012.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #12:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #13, png_pipe, from '0013.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #13:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #14, png_pipe, from '0014.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #14:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #15, png_pipe, from '0015.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #15:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #16, png_pipe, from '0016.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #16:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #17, png_pipe, from '0017.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #17:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #18, png_pipe, from '0018.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #18:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #19, png_pipe, from '0019.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #19:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #20, png_pipe, from '0020.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #20:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #21, png_pipe, from '0021.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #21:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #22, png_pipe, from '0022.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #22:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #23, png_pipe, from '0023.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #23:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #24, png_pipe, from '0024.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #24:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #25, png_pipe, from '0025.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #25:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #26, png_pipe, from '0026.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #26:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #27, png_pipe, from '0027.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #27:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #28, png_pipe, from '0028.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #28:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #29, png_pipe, from '0029.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #29:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #30, png_pipe, from '0030.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #30:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #31, png_pipe, from '0031.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #31:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #32, png_pipe, from '0032.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #32:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #33, png_pipe, from '0033.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #33:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #34, png_pipe, from '0034.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #34:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #35, png_pipe, from '0035.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #35:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #36, png_pipe, from '0036.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #36:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #37, png_pipe, from '0037.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #37:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #38, png_pipe, from '0038.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #38:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #39, png_pipe, from '0039.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #39:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #40, png_pipe, from '0040.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #40:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #41, png_pipe, from '0041.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #41:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #42, png_pipe, from '0042.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #42:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #43, png_pipe, from '0043.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #43:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #44, png_pipe, from '0044.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #44:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #45, png_pipe, from '0045.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #45:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #46, png_pipe, from '0046.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #46:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #47, png_pipe, from '0047.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #47:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #48, png_pipe, from '0048.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #48:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #49, png_pipe, from '0049.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #49:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #50, png_pipe, from '0050.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #50:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #51, png_pipe, from '0051.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #51:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #52, png_pipe, from '0052.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #52:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #53, png_pipe, from '0053.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #53:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #54, png_pipe, from '0054.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #54:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #55, png_pipe, from '0055.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #55:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #56, png_pipe, from '0056.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #56:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #57, png_pipe, from '0057.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #57:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #58, png_pipe, from '0058.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #58:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #59, png_pipe, from '0059.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #59:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #60, png_pipe, from '0060.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #60:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #61, png_pipe, from '0061.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #61:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #62, png_pipe, from '0062.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #62:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #63, png_pipe, from '0063.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #63:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #64, png_pipe, from '0064.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #64:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #65, png_pipe, from '0065.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #65:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #66, png_pipe, from '0066.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #66:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #67, png_pipe, from '0067.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #67:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #68, png_pipe, from '0068.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #68:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #69, png_pipe, from '0069.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #69:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #70, png_pipe, from '0070.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #70:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #71, png_pipe, from '0071.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #71:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #72, png_pipe, from '0072.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #72:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #73, png_pipe, from '0073.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #73:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #74, png_pipe, from '0074.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #74:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #75, png_pipe, from '0075.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #75:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #76, png_pipe, from '0076.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #76:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #77, png_pipe, from '0077.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #77:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #78, png_pipe, from '0078.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #78:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #79, png_pipe, from '0079.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #79:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #80, png_pipe, from '0080.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #80:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #81, png_pipe, from '0081.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #81:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #82, png_pipe, from '0082.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #82:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #83, png_pipe, from '0083.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #83:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #84, png_pipe, from '0084.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #84:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #85, png_pipe, from '0085.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #85:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #86, png_pipe, from '0086.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #86:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #87, png_pipe, from '0087.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #87:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #88, png_pipe, from '0088.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #88:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #89, png_pipe, from '0089.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #89:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #90, png_pipe, from '0090.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #90:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #91, png_pipe, from '0091.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #91:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #92, png_pipe, from '0092.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #92:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #93, png_pipe, from '0093.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #93:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #94, png_pipe, from '0094.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #94:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #95, png_pipe, from '0095.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #95:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #96, png_pipe, from '0096.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #96:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #97, png_pipe, from '0097.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #97:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #98, png_pipe, from '0098.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #98:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #99, png_pipe, from '0099.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #99:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #100, png_pipe, from '0100.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #100:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #101, png_pipe, from '0101.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #101:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #102, png_pipe, from '0102.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #102:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #103, png_pipe, from '0103.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #103:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #104, png_pipe, from '0104.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #104:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #105, png_pipe, from '0105.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #105:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #106, png_pipe, from '0106.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #106:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #107, png_pipe, from '0107.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #107:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #108, png_pipe, from '0108.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #108:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #109, png_pipe, from '0109.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #109:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #110, png_pipe, from '0110.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #110:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #111, png_pipe, from '0111.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #111:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #112, png_pipe, from '0112.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #112:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #113, png_pipe, from '0113.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #113:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #114, png_pipe, from '0114.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #114:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #115, png_pipe, from '0115.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #115:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #116, png_pipe, from '0116.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #116:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #117, png_pipe, from '0117.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #117:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #118, png_pipe, from '0118.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #118:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #119, png_pipe, from '0119.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #119:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #120, png_pipe, from '0120.png':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #120:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc 
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf57.84.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1600x900 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 0.20 fps, 16384 tbn, 0.20 tbc
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.108.100 libx264
Side data:
  cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=17.0 Lsize=      26kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=3540590.2kbits/s speed=0.000472x
video:26kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.124642%
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] frame I:1     Avg QP: 8.43  size: 25491
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] mb I  I16..4: 54.2% 39.4%  6.3%
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] 8x8 transform intra:39.4%
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 9.8% 14.8% 12.5%
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 47% 49%  3%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 34% 52%  6%  1%  1%  1%  1%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 20%  8%  4%  6% 12%  4%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 50%  4%  1%
[libx264 @ 000001fc0dad2b40] kb/s:40.79
```

Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct syntax to create a video out of images, use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i %04d.png -r 5 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Comment: The % are always wrong when I try it this way. Have no idea why...

Comment: Do you mean switch place of output with the color sceme one?

Comment: I tried now... the video is still not playable...

Comment: Share the full log of the command. Which player are you testing in?

Comment: Did so. I tested in VLC Media Player (OS is Windows)

Comment: You can't individually input images. Use the sequence notation in my answer.

Comment: Exactly that way? Because if I try there comes an error.... okay weird now it works? Thank you though I will tell if the file works now.

Comment: Okay I have got a video now but the pause between the frames is far too big. The frames are usually played each after the other. What should I change?

Comment: It seems like my media player just struggles with playing it... I changed framerate to 24 but it still keeps bugging during the playing process... is it too high resolution or too low quality? (1600x900 px)

Comment: How long should the video take to play?

Comment: should be ~5 seconds

Comment: Change to `-framerate 25` and remove `-r 5`.